# Lost Data after installation

Tags: data-recovery, data-loss

I wanted to get rid of Windows so I made bootable USB and installed Ubuntu but what I see now is I have only one disk "Computer" which has 290GB free and 4.5 GB used . In Windows I had 3 disk namely C , D and E . I had important data on D and E . Anyone can help me how to recover it ?

Comment: Thanks , I found the how to recover it using testdisk . I have to find a way to make partiton now .

Comment: The Ubuntu live CD/USB that you used to install Ubuntu has a built-in graphical partition editor which is named GParted.